# Al seleccionar datos en tabla, no se quedan guardadas en otra

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Tengo una ventana donde hay 2 tablas, en la primera estan las sucursales disponibles, y en la otra las asiganadas. cuando selecciono las que quiero asignar y las paso para la otra, al momento de guardar no se quedan guardadas.

adjunto imagen de la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la parte del codigo la funcion donde selecciono y donde se tiene que guardar.

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Sucursal(int AgenteId, string SucursalId)
        {
            try
            {
                List<AgentesPorSucursal> regisrtosAnteriores = await db.AgentesPorSucursal.Where(x => x.AgenteId == AgenteId).ToListAsync();
                db.AgentesPorSucursal.RemoveRange(regisrtosAnteriores);

                List<AgentesPorSucursal> registrosNuevos = new List<AgentesPorSucursal>();
                AgentesPorSucursal agentesPorSucursal;
                foreach (int i in SucursalId.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList())
                {
                    agentesPorSucursal = new AgentesPorSucursal();
                    agentesPorSucursal.AgenteId = AgenteId;
                    agentesPorSucursal.SucursalId = i;
                    db.Entry(agentesPorSucursal).State = EntityState.Added;
                    registrosNuevos.Add(agentesPorSucursal);
                }

                db.AgentesPorSucursal.AddRange(registrosNuevos);

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return Json(new { result = true, message = "La asignación se realizó con éxito. "}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
                {
                    throw new Exception("Modelo inválido.");
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                return Json(new { error = false, responseText = "Error al hacer la asignación." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Es la función que tengo al guardar los cambios mediante un botón que tengo en el view. y en el query donde valido el model

```
function AsignarAgentesSucursales() {
        $('#AgentesPorSucursal').modal('hide');
        showSpinner();

        $('#botonGuardar').prop('disabled', true);

        var url = '@Url.Action("Sucursal", "AgentesPorCategorias")'

        var form = $('#frmAsignacion');
        
        var formData = new FormData($("form")[0]);
        formData.append('AgenteId', $("#AgenteId").val());
        var subcategorias = $("#SucursalId").val() + '';
        var subArray = subcategorias.split(',')
        formData.append('SucursalId', subArray);
        
        $.getJSON({
            url: url,
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
                Swal.fire('Skills', result.message, 'success');
                $('#botonGuardar').prop('disabled', false);
                hideSpinner();
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                $('#botonGuardar').prop('disabled', false);
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                Swal.fire('Skills', 'Error al realizar la asignación. ' + err.Message, 'success');
                hideSpinner();
            }
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log('done asignación');
            hideSpinner();
            $('#botonGuardar').prop('disabled', false);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Incluye el código de la vista. Lectura sugerida para mejorar las preguntas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822  Saludos.

Comment: Y donde llamas a guardar?

Comment: Ya edite y puse la funcion donde guardo los cambios

Comment: ¿dónde está el `db.SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: Me da error en la asignación al usar el SaveChanges

Comment: ¿Sí sabes que al usar Entity Framework, para guardar los cambios, se hace uso de ese método, verdad? Edita la pregunta, agrega esa información porque es útil conocerla y también incluye lo que dice el error. Y nuevamente, te pido que leas las sugerencias que están en el primer comentario, van a incrementar la chance de obtener una buena respuesta y van a disminuir a lo que llamo "el juego de la entrevista" y también se disminuye el ir a ciegas.

Comment: Si todos los demás componentes hacen lo que tienen que hacer (la vista para mover los elementos de una lista a otra, la función que hace el post al servidor, el controlador que recibe los datos) y el problema se aisla al error que se obtiene al guardar, podría ser mas efectivo actualizar la pregunta para enfocarse en dicho error y porque puede estarse provocando.